# how to set the default value for the one particular combo box and selectable also

Tags: extjs6

There are two combo box one is "organization name" and other is "visitor type".
when iam selecting organization name as "XYZ" automatically visitor type should set to "EMPLOYEE"

When iam selecting other combo box  that is "organization name" then  combo box "visitor type" should be selectable.

please can anyone help me out .

Comment: What technology you are using?

Comment: ext js (javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use onselect function in javascript.

```
<select id="box1" onChange="changeBox(this);">
<option value="1" >1</option>
<option value="2" >2</option>
</select>
```

When you selecting the value from one value selectbox. Call onchange function like example 'changeBox'. Assign value "EMPLOYEE" to other select box. You can make function like

```
const changeBox = function (box1) {
  document.getElementById("box2").value = box1.value;
}
```

or

```
document.getElementById("box1").onchange = function(){
    document.getElementById("box2").value = this.value;
};
```

Try to use this approach you will find your solution.

Comment: how to validate id proof details using combo box , please suggest

Comment: id proof?
What exactly combo box term you are suggesting here?

Comment: id proof like aadhar card and pancard

Comment: how to validate id proof details when iam selecting aadhar card from the combo box then it should validate the aadhar card number and when iam selecting pan card then it should validate pan card number

Comment: I think you are unclear about non-technical UI flow. I have already told you about javascript technical solution.